# Why is my code not changing the value in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Im learning emberjs and I'm having difficulties changing a boolean value when a button is pressed.

This is what I am doing in the javascript:

```
App.LiensController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    addToPortfolio: function() {
      this.set('isInPortfolio', true);
      console.log('Action is Happening!');
    }
  }
});

App.LIENS=[
  {
          id: 1,
          apn: 'apn1',
          fips: '01700',
          state: 'CA',
          county: 'Los Angeles',
          address: 'somewhere st123',
          debt: 4000,
          isBiddedOn: false, //check
          isInPortfolio: false
  },
  {
          id: 2,
          apn: 'apn2',
          fips: '01744',
          state: 'FL',
          county: 'Miami',
          address: 'someplace st700',
          debt: 2000,
          isBiddedOn: false, //check
          isInPortfolio: true        
  },
  {
          id: 3,
          apn: 'apn3',
          fips: '05690',
          state: 'FL',
          county: 'Orlando',
          address: 'ExactPlace in st111',
          debt: 2500,
          isBiddedOn: false, //check
          isInPortfolio: false
  }
];
```

I also tried to use `this.toggleProperty('isInProperty');` but it is not working for me neither.

And this is the html part where the button is:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="liens">

    <h2 class="sub-header" >Liens</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>apn</th>
              <th>fips code</th>
              <th>State</th>
              <th>County</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Debt</th>
              <th>Current Bid</th>
              <th>IsInPortfolio</th>
            </tr>
          <tbody>
          {{#each lien in model}}
            <tr>
              <td>{{lien.id}}</td>
              <td>{{lien.apn}}</td>
              <td>{{lien.fips}}</td>
              <td>{{lien.state}}</td>
              <td>{{lien.county}}</td>
              <td>{{lien.address}}</td>
              <td>${{lien.debt}}</td>
              <td>{{lien.isBiddedOn}}</td> <!--Check-->
              <td>{{lien.isInPortfolio}}</td>
              <td><button id='addLien' type='button' {{action 'addToPortfolio'}}>Add</button></td>
            </tr>
          {{/each}}
          </thead>
  </script>
```

What am I doing wrong? 
here is the jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fisifu/8/edit?html,js,output

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through a list of liens in your `#each` helper, but you are trying to change a property of an individual lien. You need to use an `itemController`, which specifies the `controller` for individual lien like so:

```
{{#each lien in model itemController='lien'}}
```

Then, you need to actually create the lien controller and put the logic you had in `LiensController` into `LienController`:

```
App.LiensController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
//   actions: {
//     addToPortfolio: function() {
//       this.set('isInPortfolio', true);
//       console.log('Action is Happening!');
//     }
//   }
});

App.LienController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    addToPortfolio: function() {
      this.set('isInPortfolio', true);
      console.log('Action is Happening!');
    }
  }
});
```

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lapufu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

More on `itemController` [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html)

Comment: Nice, so everytime I want to change an individual item inside an #each helper I need to use an itemController? Is there a way not to use this?

Comment: Ember 2.x is trying to get rid of itemControllers see the following discussion http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-a-good-way-to-do-this-in-ember-2-0-no-itemcontroller-no-arraycontroller/6649. Either way, you need some way to track the state of that individual lien and itemController in your case seems like a good way to do it